# Simplest way to Read-Host in a popup window?

Tags: powershell, user-interface

I have a password for a client vpn that I need to type repeatedly from the command line. Rather than store it on the disk, I would like to query for it in my powershell $profile, store it in a variable at the scope of the shell instance and then reuse it in other scripts (so that it lives only in memory).

I could use `Read-Host` to query for the password but I would prefer a popup dialog (Paegent already pops up a dialog and I'm used to the workflow of alt+tab'ing through these and entering passwords when I reboot my computer).

Whats the easiest way to achieve the same effect as `Read-Host` but with a small popup dialog?

Comment: Get-Credential pops up a dialog box, and you can have the account name already filled in, and provide a prompt message at the top. Plus it masks the password while it's being entered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use `Get-Credentials` which masks the password, and then extract the password from the credentials.

```
#Open credential-box that masks your password when you write it.
#The inputs aren't verified, so you can use whatever username you want if it doesn't matter.
$cred = Get-Credential $env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME

#Get password
$password = $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password

#View password
$password
TestPassword123
```

If you only need the password, then you can shorten it to:

```
$password = (Get-Credential $env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME).GetNetworkCredential().Password
```

Comment: Good point, though in my case I think I'd rather have the PW in the clear to see typos

Answer (score 1):

Reaching back on old - old vb I thought of something simple that seems to work.

```
  > [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.VisualBasic")
  > $clientPassword = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("OPassword?", "Client VPN")
```